# OpenBSD: Defining a new loopback interface

Tags: openbsd, loopback

I need one more loopback interface in my OpenBSD 6.1, with the IP address 127.0.0.2.

I can create it by hand with the command:

```
ifconfig lo1 127.0.0.2
```

And to have it at boot time, I just inserted that command into `/etc/rc.local`.

I have researched for a more standard way to do that, was not successful.

Having it in `/etc/rc.local` also means I only have that interface late in the boot process.

How may I configure it in a cleaner "OpenBSD" way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As hinted at in [`lo(4)`](http://man.openbsd.org/lo), you may create `/etc/hostname.lo1`:

```
inet 127.0.0.2 255.0.0.0
```

This will create the `lo1` interface when the boot process runs `/etc/netstart`.  With that file in place, you may also set up the interface without rebooting through

```
$ doas sh /etc/netstart lo1
```

The interface is reported as

```
lo1: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 32768
        index 4 priority 0 llprio 3
        groups: lo
        inet 127.0.0.2 netmask 0xff000000
```

by `ifconfig`.

For further info, see [`hostname.if(5)`](http://man.openbsd.org/hostname.if), [`netstart(8)`](http://man.openbsd.org/netstart) and [`ifconfig(8)`](http://man.openbsd.org/ifconfig).

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I am getting my feet wet in OpenBSD in a personal netbook as a pilot/(re)introduction to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason for this to be an *additional* network interface, note that you do not *have* to have a second interface just in order to have a second IP address in 127.0.0.0/8.  You can add the second IP address to the *existing* loopback interface:

```
# echo >> /etc/hostname.lo0 inet alias 127.0.0.2 255.255.255.255
#
```

Note that the alias gets a tighter (/32) netmask; cf. https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq6.html#Setup.aliases.

**NB:** Be aware that if you use `ifconfig -a`, it only lists each interface's first address. You can use `ifconfig -A` instead to see all addresses, including aliases.

Comment: I defined a interface to give it to some particular software at the time. Switched back to freebsd.